# XSL for-each only showing first tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML Code:

```
<pregunta tipo="bool" id="A03" tema="2">
    <enunciado>¿Distingue el lenguaje HTML mayúsculas/minúsculas?</enunciado>
    <respuesta>1- Sí</respuesta>
    <respuesta>2- No</respuesta>        
</pregunta>
```

And this XSL Code:

```
<body>
    <xsl:for-each select="pregunta">
        <xsl:value-of select="enunciado" />
        <xsl:value-of select="respuesta" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
```

I want to print the "enunciado" tag and all of the "respuesta" tags for each "pregunta" tag, but it just shows the first "respuesta" tag. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over `respuesta` in some way, e.g. using `xsl:for-each`:

```
<body>
    <xsl:for-each select="pregunta">
        <xsl:value-of select="enunciado" />
        <xsl:for-each select="respuesta">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
```